# PHP Array Key-Pair Value From 2 Separate Array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        $person = array("azizul@gmail.com", "yong@gmail.com", "liew@gmail.com");
        $id = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
        $newArray = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($person); $j++) {
                $newArray[$id[$i]] = $person[$j];
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($newArray);
    ?>
```

The output:

```
{"1":"liew@gmail.com","2":"liew@gmail.com","3":"liew@gmail.com","4":"liew@gmail.com","5":"liew@gmail.com"}
```

The output that I wish to create:

```
{"1":"azizul@gmail.com","2":"yong@gmail.com","3":"liew@gmail.com","4":"azizul@gmail.com","5":"yong@gmail.com"}
```

What do i missed? Appreciate for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$person = array("azizul@gmail.com", "yong@gmail.com", "liew@gmail.com");
        $id = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
        $newArray = array();
        $j=0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
            if(count($person) == $j){
             $j=0; 
           }
            $newArray[$id[$i]] = $person[$j++];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what problem this is supposed to solve, but what it looks like your after is

```
$persons_count = count($persons);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
    $modded_index = $persons_count % $i;
    $newArray[$i] = $person[$modded_index];
}
```

At least that code will get you to your wanted solution.